# Как сделать вывод фото в telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Есть код и я хочу что бы вместо текста фото1 и т.д. были какие либо фотографии и они воспроизводились случайным образом когда нажималась кнопка фото

```
import telebot
import random
from telebot import types
from PIL import Image
sl={
    '1':'фото1',
    '2':'фото2',
    '3':'фото3',
    '4':'фото4',
    '5':'фото5',
    '6':'фото6',
    '7':'фото7',
    '8':'фото8',
    '9':'фото9'
    }
sk ={
    '1':'текст1',
    '2':'текст2',
    '3':'текст3',
    '4':'текст4',
    '5':'текст5',
    '6':'текст6',
    '7':'текст7',
    '8':'текст8',
    '9':'текст9'        
}
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN');
def ds (message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Фото', callback_data='yes')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Милые слова', callback_data='no')
    markup.add(item1, item2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Выбрать действие:', reply_markup=markup)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'yes':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text= sl[str(random.randint(1,9))])
        elif call.data == 'no':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text= sk[str(random.randint(1,9))])  
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Как мне нужно написать `if call.data == 'yes': bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text= sl[str(random.randint(1,9))])`  вот эту команду что бы работала с фото?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте так:

1. Замените словарь `sl` на следующий:

```
sl={
    '1':'путь к фото1',
    '2':'путь к фото2',
    ...
    }
```

2. Замените код отправки на следующий:

```
if call.data == 'yes':
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text= sk[str(random.randint(1,9))])
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open(sl[str(random.randint(1,9))])
```

Функция `send_photo()` отправляет в чат фотографию.

Comment: Помог мой ответ?